# Mercurial hg no suitable response from remote hg error

Tags: ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg

Trying setup mercurial SVM on my windows server (2008 RC) from last couple of hours. I am stuck on this error when I try to clone my repo from the client machine.

```
Error:  no suitable response from remote hg
```

The server that I am running has SSH access (SSH running on port 1667). I also have a remote access to it.

I tried to clone using command as well as with the help of tortoisehg gui client. Commands I tried is:

```
hg clone ssh://myuser@myremoteip:1667//D:/Mercurial Projects/testproj E:\Mercurial\testproj-clone

hg clone --remotecmd D:/Program Files/TortoiseHg/hg --verbose -- ssh://myuser@myremoteip:1667//D:/Mercurial Projects/testproj E:\Mercurial\testproj-clone
```

but no success so far.

I also added following line in global setting at client side to give remote path of hg on server but no luck:

```
[ui]
remotecmd = D:/Program Files/TortoiseHg/hg
```

Please help me...

Comment: Do you really get nothing except that single error line even when you're using `--verbose` as I see in one of your examples?

Comment: Yes I just get that error nothing else

Comment: Try getting the space out of the remote cmd path.  Quoting the value might help, but if D:/Progra~1/TortoiseHg/hg is still valid (I've not been on windows since win95) then try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was that my Python version was older than the one I needed. I was trying to set it up with Python 2.6. I followed another tutorial with Python 2.7 and latest Mercurial version (2.8.1)

Anyone with Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7+ should follow [this tutorial](https://justinchronicles.wordpress.com/tag/windows-server-2008-r2/).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and in my case it was that the computer had both TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHG installed. Both TortoiseHG and TortoiseSVN have a command `TortoisePlink.exe` that they use. However, due to the PATH, TortoiseHG was using TortoiseSVN's `TortoisePlink.exe`.

Uninstalling TortoiseSVN solved the problem for me.

You may open a "cmd" window and type:

```
where TortoisePlink.exe
```

to check what TortoisePlink.exe is used.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem after updating TortoiseHg. It turned out the location of *TortoisePlink.exe* has changed. I had it set explicitly to *C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe* in *mercurial.ini* and I had to change it to *C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg**\lib\**TortoisePlink.exe*.